# Load php class located outside symfony project

Tags: php, class, symfony, namespaces, load

I am building a frontend symfony app for a project with the current folder structure:

```
+---app
|   +---conf
|   +---lib
|   |   +---ca
|   |   |   +---Search
+---frontend
|   +---app
|   +---bin
|   +---src
|   |   \---PublicBundle
|   |       +---Controller
```

The app folder on root is where another (non symfony app) is located. It is a php app.

Inside the frontend folder is where symfony project is being built.

I am trying to load from inside the symfony app (from the public controller) a class from the other php app (a class inside the ca subfolder) but when I try to, symfony returns a namespace exception with the tip: Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

It is correct to load a class from outside a symfony project like is, and if it is how is it done?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If your app implemented autoload and namespaces like PSR then answer -- yes.

Comment: So far autoload is an option and if it is required I can use it. I am starting the project and faced this problem. I read about psr in this url http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/psr4_class_loader.html. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: I'm on it. I am not more than a begginer at symfony so it is kinda problematic for me so far. If I understood it, the steps should be: instantiate the loader, add a path as a prefix, register it and then load the class?

Comment: Yess, it right.

Comment: Let me try it if I can go with it and I'll feedback you

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure if this is PSR. Here is the class I want to load http://paste.ofcode.org/qBDVKHKkEesckYbWN4vzRh . Do you consider load it by PSR or PSR4 an option for this? Thanks in advance